# finding transition point of data slope

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am wondering if there is a method to approach this problem.
The reason I need this is because for a certain trend of data I need to use a specific formula and for the next trend of the data I need to use a different formula.
Also, the data is not simple but there are two distinct slopes.
All data points are in excel cells.I haven't started the code yet. I am thinking about using (0,1,2,3,4) data points and finding slope and keep moving by 1 (1,2,3,4,5) then somehow calculate a difference in the 2 slopes and when they are significant. to call that the transition point

[image]

Comment: It really helps if you provide source data and expected results or at least a graph of the data.  Is there noise to the data, is there a hard hinge point you need to find or more of a transition area, how exact does the answer need to be, what defines "significant"

Comment: s32.postimg.org/bbu5ink5h/Capture.jpg

Comment: I have program to delete noisy data... not an issue.

Comment: What about just finding the minimum point on the x-axis?

Comment: Yea I guess for this project that could work!!!

Comment: I did something like this once for a friend.  I think the term they were using was rainbow casting.  They were getting real time data readings that were going up and down kind of like a sinusoidal pattern.  They need to find all the maximum and minimums.  I basically took your same approach.  I averaged the slope of a line  over something like 20 points and made a list of points where the slope changed from positive to negative.  Then I went back to the original data and searched for max/min between the points where the line changed positive to negative.  Ergo I think your approach should work

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to reduce the problem to finding inflection points. This can be defined as point where the data flattens briefly to either resume a trend, change it (but in the same direction), or reverse it. You can do this by finding small time clusters with slope of zero. Or a better idea would be to divide your y data into horizontal bins. If a certain threshold of number of data points in a bin is reached, a change in trend is in progress. You can vary the inflection sensitivity by varying the bin size and/or varying the minimum number of points in a bin.